# Convert column to a different value based on another columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like

```
ID | Name | ProdID | Model | StudID
-----------------------------------
1  |  A   |   3    |  hey  |   6
2  |  B   |   4    |  he   |   7
2  |  C   |   5    |  hi   |   8
```

I need to make just `Model` and `StudID` values to `N/A` when `ProdID` is 4 and 5

```
ID | Name | ProdID | Model | StudID
-----------------------------------
1  |  A   |   3    |  hey  |   6
2  |  B   |   4    |  N/A  |   N/A
2  |  C   |   5    |  N/A  |   N/A
```

Here's a small sample of what I've done so far

```
SELECT      
     ID,
     Name,
     CASE 
          WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, ProdID) = 4 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, Model) = 'N/A'
     ..
```

Comment: `... case when prodid in (4, 5) then 'N/A' else Model end ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT      
 ID,
 Name,
 ProdID,
 CASE 
      WHEN ProdID IN( 4,5) THEN 'N/A'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, Model)
 END AS 'Model',
 CASE 
      WHEN ProdID IN( 4,5) THEN 'N/A'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, StudID)
 END AS 'StudID'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be quite careful about types.

- Don't convert values to strings unless you have to.
- When using `convert()` or `cast()` *always* include a length for `varchar()`.

So:

```
SELECT ID, Name, ProdId,
       (CASE WHEN ProdId IN (4, 5) THEN Model ELSE 'N/A' END) as Model,
       (CASE WHEN ProdId IN (4, 5) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), StudId) ELSE 'N/A' END) as StudId
       ...
```

Note that you need conversion for `StudId`, assuming the value is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID ,  Name ,  ProdID ,  
CASE WHEN ProdID IN (4,5) THEN 'N/A' ELSE Model END Model ,
CASE WHEN ProdID IN (4,5) THEN 'N/A' ELSE StudID END   StudID from @Table1
```